# Find out if running in WPF or console mode (c#)

Tags: c#, wpf

Well
this is a really simple question, the search tearms are just not that great.

How do I check in some library if I am currently running as a console application, vs. a WPF window application?

Thanks for any tips,

Chris

Comment: If you are asking this question you are doing something wrong, even if we don't consider it's technically possible to have an app with both a console and WPF UI, what if your lib is called from a WinForms app? or from an ASP.NET app running under IIS? or some completely new kind of applicaiton that will be introduced in a future version of .net?

Comment: In my case I have a reporting engine that is capable of creating a pdf file or displaying a preview.  (Allowing preview related portions of code to be skipped/ignored when the engine is called from a console app allows it to execute faster / not crash trying to do wpf related stuff for an app that does not support it.)

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether the current thread is a WPF UI thread by checking `Dispatcher.Current`.

Answer (score 2):

There's more, what if your library method is called from a worker thread?  You didn't tell why you need to know, preventing a good answer.  One approach is that the app that uses your library never has any trouble knowing whether its console or WPF.  Expose a property to allow it to tell you.  Another is using events so the app can simply implement the event handler to its liking.  Dependency Injection is another.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the executed statements are running in a WPF host with the following statement:

```
if (System.Windows.Application.Current != null)
{
//statements for WPF mode
}
else
{
//statements for non WPF mode...
}
```

For this you must reference PresentationFramework.dll

Answer (score 0):

ILDasm will have an entry in the manifest as follows :

```
.subsystem 0x0003       // WINDOWS_CUI

.subsystem 0x0002       // WINDOWS_GUI
```

based on the subsystemtype you can tell if its GUI or CUI.

This information is also available from the following command :

```
dumpbin ConsoleApplication1.exe /headers
```

From your library query for entry assembly and get its full path(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase) and then you can issue any of these command to know the subsystem.